# ImagePanel isn't showing in my jar file with netbeans

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, embedded-resource

i used a class Imagepanel  to show a background image to my panel in  netbeans  .It successfully works when running it from the IDE netbeans 6.8 ,but when i run it from the jar file it doesn't show the image .Please help me to solve this problem .Thanks for your remarks .
Here is my code ImagePanel.java

```
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Image;
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;



 class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

   private Image img;

   public ImagePanel(String img ) {


      this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());


}

   public ImagePanel(Image img) {
     this.img = img;
     Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
     setPreferredSize(this.getMaximumSize());
     setMinimumSize(size);
     setMaximumSize(size);
     setSize(this.getMaximumSize());
     setLayout(null);
   }

   @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
     }

 }
```

I have created my panel which is in another class like this where my image is in the directory images under src. Thanks in advance .

```
ImagePanel pan2 = new ImagePanel("src/images/tarif.png");
```

Comment: 1) By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`. 2) `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);` 3) `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paingComponent(g);`

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thanks for your response i updated my code as you told me and it worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel
{
Image image;
public BackgroundPanel(String path)
{
try
{
image = (new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path))).getImage();
}
catch(Exception e){/*handled in paintComponent()*/}
}
    @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}
}
```

this code worked and i call the class like this

```
String path ="/images/tarif.png";
JPanel pan2=new BackgroundPanel(path);
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  Thanks for reporting back.  :)